# Are a monster's innate melee/ranged spell attack abilities blocked by a target's Antimagic Field?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack, antimagic-field

Certain creatures have abilities listed as being melee or ranged spell attacks, e.g. the [Efreeti](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Efreeti#content)'s Hurl Flame action.

Are these considered magic that an [*antimagic field*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Antimagic%20Field#content) will block? Or are they considered to be innate powers that AMF can't block?

Answer (score 12):

### Spell attacks are blocked by AMF

[Per the Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) linked by Gandalfmeansme in his comment:

> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - **Is it a spell attack?**
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature is magical [and therefore Antimagic Field would protect against it].

Answer (score 0):

### If it is magical in nature, then yes, the anti-magic field does block it.

According to the description of [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field):

> This area is divorced from the magical energy that suffuses the multiverse. Within the sphere, spells can't be cast, summoned creatures disappear, and even magic items become mundane.

Though a spell attack is not technically a spell, it is magical, and thus it fails within the sphere. There is a way to ignore that though.

> Spells and other magical effects, **except those created by an artifact or a deity** [emphasis mine], are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.

Otherwise, anything magical just doesn't happen.

This doesn't stop anything non-magical from taking effect, so if you rule that an effect is not at all magical in nature, then it should work just fine! That said, I would find it incredibly difficult to justify a Hurl Flame ability not being magical, and I would not allow it to occur within an *antimagic field*.

[Rykara's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138841/48837) shows the relevant Sage Advice on whether something is magical or not. Anything that falls under that criteria is indeed magical, and can be blocked by the anti-magic field.

Comment: Since the title asked one question and the body of the question asked the opposite, I edited the title to bring it in line with the body. You may want to clarify which of those your header was responding to. ...Also, "a spell attack is still a spell" is not true. Can you cite anything in the rules that supports your argument?

Comment: This answer might benefit from the sage advice compendium's discussion of [how you know whether or not something is magical](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf). (which can be found by clicking on the link in this comment, and finding the question labeled **"is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?"**)

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme: Good point. Though spell attacks don't necessarily originate from spells (see also: the Sun Soul monk), they are still magical by the game's definition, and affected by AMF.

Comment: @V2Blast Oh, I didn't even realize that was one of the criteria to make something magical! I only meant that MrSpudtastic's (already good) answer could benefit from mentioning the criteria for what is and isn't magical.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I have updated the answer, and hopefully it is more useful now!